# SSRS report on sharepoint becomes blank when clicking back

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, reporting-services

We're displaying SSRS reports using report viewer webpart. On Internet Explorer, we face a quite strange problem. Normally, reports display just fine. However, sometimes (yes, sometimes, not always), after navigating around, and then click browser's back button, the page does show up, but reports become blank.

We did investigate but couldn't really find out the reason. it seems that sometimes, clicking back will lead to a different DOM structure!

Anyone getting the same problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2010 or 2013? Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Not really an "Answer" so I am just commenting, but I do see that too. I see it on some initial page loads as well. That is, navigate to the page with the report viewer web part and it doesn't load.. hit refresh, and then it loads fine.  We are SharePoint 2010, SSRS 2012, and various IE version 8 through 10.  I will be watching this thread for ideas too. :)

Comment: We're using Sharepoint foundation 2010, with IE 11. It also occasionally happens on Firefox.